# Запрос авторизации направлен на порт веб приложения

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Есть проект, в котором два веб-приложения(Security и Web api). Они крутятся на IIS Express сервере при запуске в VS.

В Security проходит проверка логина и выдача токена. Приложение при запуске разворачивается по адресу `http://localhost:37575/`

При старте проекта, веб приложение расположенное по адресу `http://localhost:37574/`, начинает работу с авторизации. При отправке post-запроса (логин, пароль) происходит ошибка 404, а путь к контроллеру таков `http://localhost:37574/token/password`, то есть в root указан порт web-приложения, а не security-приложения.

Как я понимаю, то в связи с этим и ошибка 404. Он не может найти нужный контроллер? Потому что смотрит не тот порт и, следовательно, не в то приложение. В связи с этим вопрос, что необходимо отладить, чтобы была правильная адресация?

Нужный метод апи вызывается из приложения Security:
Есть `[RoutePrefix("token")]`

```
[RoutePrefix("token")]
public class TokenController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    private readonly IActiveDirectoryService _adService;
    private readonly IRefreshTokenService _refreshTokenService;

    public TokenController(IUserService userService, IActiveDirectoryService adService, IRefreshTokenService refreshTokenService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _adService = adService;
        _refreshTokenService = refreshTokenService;
    }

    [Route("password")]
    [HttpPost]
    public TokenResult Password(PasswordModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState));

        try
        {
            var user = _adService.Authenticate(model.Login, model.Password);
            return CreateTokenResultFor(user);
        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, ex.Message));
        }
    }
```

В веб-контролере вызывается метод post:

```
authenticate(login: string, password: string) {
        return this.$http.post<TokenResult>("security/token/password", { grant_type: "password", login: login, password: password }).then(response=> {
            this.completeAuth(response.data, "password");
        });
    }
```

Пробовал ставить endpoint `http://localhost:37575/security/token/password`, но это не решило проблему.

Comment: в методе контроллера авторизации надо вызывать нужный вам метод api-секьюрити. для этого нужно добавить endpoint к прилинкованному сервису, в референсах же нужно , чтобы был прокси к этому сервису, для  вызова его методов.

Comment: @Konst, спасибо за информацию. Могли бы Вы уточнить: референс это раздел приложения в visual studio, там надо делать изменения? И можно подробнее, что именно необходимо сделать, имею ввиду действия. Спасибо)

Comment: Здравствуйте, в stackOverflow есть специальная кнопка для вствки кода, выглядит она примерно так: {}.
Если вы будете добавлять код именно таким образом, его будет проще читать и копировать, а значит больше людей попробуют решить вашу проблему!

Comment: создайте новый проект в вашем солюшене (там где ваш основной сайт) который будет прокси-секьюрити. в этом проекте добавьте ссылку (add service reference) на ваш развёрнутый сервис по адресу http ://localhost:37575/ . студия сгенерит требуемый прокси (по необходимости подключите ссылки на библиотеки моделей вашего сервиса). сам прокси-проект подключите как ссылку в проект основного веб-сайта и настройте в его конфиге endpoint на ваш развёрнутый сервис api-секьюрити, пример: <endpoint address="http ://localhost:37575/Auth.Security.svc/" ...

Comment: вызывайте после этого уже методы api-секьюрити через прокси напрямую в котроллере основного web-сайта (сделайте новый если нужно с методом аутентификации)

Comment: @Konst- спасибо за комментарий, новый для меня способ решения проблемы, я бы стал "городить огород" c nginx и маршрутизацией через него. Может, оформите как ответ?

Comment: @Konst спасибо! Есть нюансы. 1. Приложение рабочее и написано давно. 2. Аналогичное приложение с аналогичной архитектурой и настройками(по крайней мере, которые я смотрел) идентичны. И то приложение отлично работает.
Я бы хотел восстановить работоспособность проекта без добавления каких либо вещей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально решение было настроено на работу сервера IIS, а не IIS Express. Тем самым с текущей конфигурацией требовалось разворачивать решение при наличии IIS.
Для решения данной проблемы потребовалось развернуть IIS и после открыть решение. Visual Studio автоматически развернула проект, как надо.